# ¿Cómo puedo terminar o interrumpir un forEach?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Quiero que regrese o termine el proceso donde arrojo el mensaje, ya intente con `return` y break y no me ha funcionado:

```
$scope.folios.forEach(function (value) {
            console.log($scope.folios)
            if (value.seleccionado) {
                if (value.seleccionado.modalidad == "ORD"){
                    if(value.seleccionado.libertad=="S"){
                        elementos_seleccionados.push(value);
                    }
                }
                else{
                    alert('No es posible generar layout, no cumplen con regla ORD+LSF');
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: quiero que regrese o termine el proceso donde arrojo el mensaje, ya intente con return y breack y no me ah funcionado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> No hay una forma de interrumpir un .foreach en AngularJS.

Te recomiendo usar `Native For` de `javascript`, que de hecho es mucho mas rápido que otros bucles.

El equivalente a tu código seria:

```
for (var i = 0, len = $scope.folios.length; i < len; i++) {
   console.log($scope.folios);
            if ($scope.folios[i].seleccionado) {
                if ($scope.folios[i].seleccionado.modalidad == "ORD"){
                    if($scope.folios[i].seleccionado.libertad=="S"){
                        elementos_seleccionados.push(value);
                    }
                }
                else{
                    alert('No es posible generar layout, no cumplen con regla ORD+LSF');
                    break;
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias lo intentare

Comment: Hola de nuevo, me arroja unidefined en $scope.folios[i].seleccionado.modalidad == "ORD, las imprime para ver su valor, ya que realice una prueba donde si cumplian con los valores y aun asi arroja el error o el mensaje

Answer (score 3):

No hay un break en el forEach de javascript, podes intentar tirando una excepcion, como dicen en la [respuesta de stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641347/how-to-short-circuit-array-foreach-like-calling-break), de todas formas recomiendo que no uses foreach y en su lugar uses un simple for.

Comment: muchas gracias lo intentare